# Can't run Rails server because of json gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems

I get an error while trying to run the rails server. Seems like I can't install the json gem properly. When I first tried to install the gems, I got the 1.8.2 version of the json gem. For some reason I got the same error messages as attached when I tried to run the server. In order to install the 1.7.7 version of json, I have uninstalled the 1.8.2 gem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance:)

```
$ rails s
Could not find json-1.7.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 10.0.3
[...]
Using rack-ssl 1.3.3

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/annemarit/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.7.7/.gitignore
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.

$ gem install json -v '1.7.7'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/annemarit/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.7.7/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

When permission is denied, this can sometimes mean that you installed the gem with sudo permission meaning that you have to have root access to install/update. This happened once to me where I was installing everything with root access since I was signed in as root and forgot.

The solution I found was to uninstall everything and reinstall as non sudo. It was a painful process, but it fixed my no permission error. If you continue as root and keep installing everything as sudo, you will run into major problems later as well, so never run in sudo when developing RoR applications.

I hope this helps!